# Android App to show internals

Tags: android

Is there an android app which can show the internals of the android app which myself have created or preferably even other Apps. The internals I am looking for are:

- Activities in the app
- ContentProviders in the App
- Services
- Broadcast Recievers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an app yourself, the [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) class contains information about these components, you can obtain instances from the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html). Otherwise, there are some apps for this, the first one I found is called [Stanley](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.xgouchet.packageexplorer).